# value of UseContext is undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to pass my user into a context so that I can call him at another place in my application. When I pass the data to another screens it is undefined.

`ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'user.name')`

I created a fake user to test the context

I use :
"react-native": "0.70.5",

```js
    import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
    import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
    import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";
    import { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";
    import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
    import UserContext from "../commons/UserContext";
    
    WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
    const fakeUser = {
      name: "John Doe",
      picture: "...",
    };
    
    const GoogleAuth = ({ navigation }) => {
      navigation = useNavigation();
      const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
      const [user, setUser] = useState(fakeUser);
      const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
        clientId: "clientId",
        iosClientId: "iosClientId",
        androidClientId: "androidClientId",
      });
    
      // skip because fake user in useState not importante
      useEffect(() => {
      
      }, [response, accessToken]);
    
      // skip because fake user in useState not importante
      async function fetchUserInformations() {
      
      }
    
      // importante with provider
      const ShowUserInfo = () => {
        if (user) {
          return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Successfully connected</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Welcome</Text>
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: user.picture }}
                  style={styles.picture}
                ></Image>
                <Text style={styles.subText}>{user.name}</Text>
                <Button
                  disabled={!request}
                  title="Acceder au tableau de bord"
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("MapTab", {
                      screen: "Home",
                      params: { user: user },
                    });
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </UserContext.Provider>
          );
        }
      };
   

   return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
          // if there is user
          {user && <ShowUserInfo />}
          // if there is no user
          {user === null && (
            <>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Welcome</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subText}>Please Login</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  disabled={!request}
                  onPress={() => {
                    promptAsync();
                  }}
                >
                  <SvgUri width="35%" height="35%" uri=".svg" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </>
          )}
        </View>
      );
    };
```

My UserContext.js

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext({});

export default UserContext;
```

Home.js

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useFocusEffect, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import UserContext from "../commons/UserContext";


const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  navigation = useNavigation();

  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("User logged in", user);
    };
  }, [user]);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("beforeRemove", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation])
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.banner}>
        <View style={styles.leftContent}>
          <Button
            color={"#008080"}
            title="go to map"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("Planisphere");
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rightContent}>
          <View style={styles.rightTextContent}>
            <Text style={styles.name}>
              {user.name ? user.name : user.email}
            </Text>
          </View>
          {user.picture ? (
            <Image source={{ uri: user.picture }} style={styles.picture} />
          ) : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Naivgation.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Login from "../screens/Login";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Settings from "../screens/Settings";
import Planisphere from "../screens/Planisphere ";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import GoogleAuth from "../screens/GoogleAuth";
import { View } from "react-native";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MapTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        gestureEnabled: false,
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          canGoBack: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => <View style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        options={{
          gestureEnabled: false,
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => <View style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }} />,
        }}
        name="Planisphere"
        component={Planisphere}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        options={{
          gestureEnabled: false,
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => <View style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }} />,
        }}
        name="Settings"
        component={Settings}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="MapTab"
          component={MapTab}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="GoogleAuth"
          component={GoogleAuth}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

app.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Navigation from "./src/commons/Navigation";

export default function App() {
  return <Navigation />;
}
```

I try to store my user in my UserContext so that I can call it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The log output you showed is basically a private API and not something you should care about. To read from the context you need to `useContext` in a component that is inside of the provider. Logging the `UserContext` itself won't give you anything worthwhile.

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";
import { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import UserContext from "../commons/UserContext";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
const fakeUser = {
  name: "John Doe",
  picture: "...",
};

const UserInfo = () => {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Successfully connected</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Welcome</Text>
      <Image source={{ uri: user.picture }} style={styles.picture}></Image>
      <Text style={styles.subText}>{user.name}</Text>
      <Button
        disabled={!request}
        title="Acceder au tableau de bord"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("MapTab", {
            screen: "Home",
            params: { user: user },
          });
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="LogContextUser"
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("context", user);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const GoogleAuth = ({ navigation }) => {
  navigation = useNavigation();
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(fakeUser);
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    clientId: "clientId",
    iosClientId: "iosClientId",
    androidClientId: "androidClientId",
  });

  // skip because fake user in useState not importante
  useEffect(() => {}, [response, accessToken]);

  // skip because fake user in useState not importante
  async function fetchUserInformations() {}

  // importante with provider
  const ShowUserInfo = () => {
    if (user) {
      return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
          <UserInfo />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your  answer I have rephrased my question in my topic

Comment: Ah so this is because the screens themselves are outside of the context. You need to hoist the `<UserContext.Provider value={user}>` to above your screen declarations (assuming you use react-navigation). So the whole app is a child of the context. This will include moving up logic around fetching the user.

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to put it directly in my app.js? For the navigation I have delocalized it in another component. Yes I use react Navigation

Comment: Or do you mean that I have to add on each screen UserContext.provider?

Comment: No, rather the Provider (there will only be one) is much higher in the react component tree. So wherever you call `Stack.Navigator` etc etc, it needs to wrap those such that all screens are contained within one canonical user provider.

Comment: (So yeh probably app.js)

Comment: In my app.js I call my component "Navigation", if I add UserContext my app.js what value should I assign to it knowing that my user is not set here? I updated my topic with my navigation and my app.js

Comment: You will need to move all the logic that fetches the user upwards as well -- this kind of thing can be annoying to refactor but there's no other way. Because the login is a user triggered event and as you correctly mention, it wont be there at first , you need to pass down more than the `user` object in the context. You should also pass down callbacks like `setUser` so that components that need to write to that value can change it even though its much higher in the component tree.